# Good online resource to learn basic anatomy and structure of webpage?

Tags: html, css

I'd say I have pretty good grasp of core concepts of html/css/jQuery. 
But I still have hard time trying to create a web page where it involves a lot of
use of div containers, making menu bars, and similar layouts.

Answer (score 0):

There are some systems to help simplify layout, or at least prototype them.  For example, http://960.gs is one that I've started from for many sites.